# View the uploaded files in rails 4 where i used f.file_field tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, rubygems

I've been trying to upload the files. Which i figured out a way with rails 4 , with this code

```
<%= form_for @photo do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

now that the files are being uploaded and stored in a place, iam not able to view it in my homepage..

I need to know what code to be placed below the view form or the def show.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thank you so much. :D

My controller code =>

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /photos
  # GET /photos.json
  def index
    #@photos = Photo.all

     @photos = Photo.order('created_at')
  end

  # GET /photos/1
  # GET /photos/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /photos/new

  def destroy

    @photo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to photos_url, notice: 'Photo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  def new
    @photo = Photo.new

  end

  # GET /photos/1/edit
  def edit
  end


 def upload
  uploaded_io = params[:person][:picture]
 File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end

  # POST /photos
  # POST /photos.json
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
    uploaded_io = params[:photo][:photo]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
       file.write(uploaded_io.read)
     end
    if @photo.save
      flash[:success] = "The photo was added!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end




  private




  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :title, :video)
  end
end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update(photo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /photos/1
  # DELETE /photos/1.json





  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_photo
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:title)
    end
```

index.html.erb =>

```
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Photos</h1>



<table>


<%= render @photos %>


    <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= photo.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', photo %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_photo_path(photo) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', photo, method: :delete %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>


<br>

<%= link_to 'New Photo', new_photo_path %>
<%= link_to 'Add File', new_boss_path %>
```

---

**Update**

[image: This is my output after your solution sir, i want to view the files that ive uploaded]

This is my output after your solution sir, i want to view the files that ive uploaded And also the original_filename is not passed at the back end.

Comment: Can you specify what are the fields in your `Photo` model?

Comment: What does your `Photo` model have?

Comment: id                 | integer                     | not null default nextval('photos_id_seq'::regclass)
 title              | character varying           | 
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 image_file_name    | character varying           | 
 image_content_type | character varying           | 
 image_file_size    | integer                     | 
 image_updated_at   | timestamp without time zone | 


these are all the fields...

Comment: Where did the `image_content_type` field come from?

Answer (score 1):

> the files are being uploaded and stored in a place,

The main problem you have is that you're not able to *reference* the file after it's uploaded:

```
def create
  @photo = Photo.new photo_params #-> only saves :title

  uploaded_io = params[:photo][:photo]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
     file.write(uploaded_io.read) #-> saves file
  end

  if @photo.save #-> you're only saving title
    ...
```

What you need is to add an identifier to your `Photo` model (typically `original_filename`):

```
#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @photo    = Photo.new photo_params
    @uploaded = upload(params[:photo][:photo])

    if @photo.save
      redirect_to root_path, success: "The photo was added!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).require(:title).merge(original_filename: params[:photo][:photo][:original_filename])
  end

  def upload obj
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', obj.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(obj.read)
    end
  end
end
```

This will mean you have to add the `original_filename` attribute to your `photos` table; it will give you the ability to reference the photo in your `index`:

```
#app/views/photos/index.html.erb
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag "public/uploads/#{photo.original_filename}" %>
<% end %>
```

--

To perform the migration, you'll have to use:

```
$ rails g migration AddFilenameToPhoto

# db/migrate/add_filename_to_photo____.rb
class AddFilenameToPhoto < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :photos do |t|
      t.string :original_filename
    end 
  end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

---

**Paperclip**

The alternative, of course, is to use [`Paperclip`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) (or [`Carrierwave`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)).

Whilst I imagine you have your own reasons for going manual, using a pre-baked `gem` puts a tested pattern on your system.

As such, you may wish to use the following:

```
#Gemfile
gem "paperclip"

$ rails g migration AddPaperclipToPhotos

#db/migrate/add_paperclip_to_photos_____.rb
class AddPaperclipToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_attachment :photos, :photo
  end
end

#app/models/photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo
end

#app/controllers/photos_controller.rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new photo_params
    @photo.save
  end

  private

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :photo)
  end 
end

#app/views/photos/index.html.erb
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag photo.photo.url %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

**Yes** you can upload videos through `Paperclip`.

The most important thing is using the correct [transcoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding): It used to be [`ffmpeg`](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg), but is now [`paperclip-av-transcoder`](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder):

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment, styles: { lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {small: "x200>", medium: "x300>", large: "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { geometry: "100x100#", format: 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { geometry: "300x300#", format: 'jpg', time: 10}}}, processors: [:transcoder]

  def is_image?
    attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
  end

  def is_video?
    attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(video)
  end
end
```

Here is [some old code](https://github.com/joehilton/hpvideos/blob/master/app/models/attachment.rb) which works.

You'll then be able to output it as follows:

```
#app/views/model/show.html.erb
<% if model.attachment %>
  <% if model.attachment.instance.is_image? %>
    <%= image_tag model.attachment.url %>
  <% elsif model.attachment.instance.is_video? %>
    <%= video_tag model.attachment.url %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, there are a lot of things to add. The above is the most basic way you'd get it working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time sir.

But I'm still not able to view the images on my browser. :(

Comment: Thanks for the update - have you got a Github repo I could look at? Also, can you post the rendered HTML for your images?

Comment: Sorry i do not have a GITHUB REPO, i will be able to provide you with all the details u need. Thank you.

Comment: Sir i need to upload a video and view it on the browser , that is my task. Is that possible with ruby on rails and can u explain it to me or show me any tutorial. please . thank you :)

Comment: Yes it's possible. I've done it before - I'll write an update for you

Comment: I've figured out the answer finally sir... Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Can you show your code in your question? It would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The index.html.erb file which will view the PDF file and also the VIDEO which is uploaded in your database.

```
> <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
> 
> 
> <table>   <thead>
>     <tr>
>       <th>File name</th>
>       <th>File path</th>
>       <th colspan="3"></th>
>     </tr>   </thead>
> 
>   <tbody>
>     <% @memories.each do |memory| %>
>       <tr>
>         
>         <td>
>         <object width="500" height="600" type="application/pdf" data="/uploads/<%=memory.file_name%>?#zoom=50&toolbar=0"
> id="pdf_content">
>         </object>
>         </td>  
>           
>         <td><%= video_tag("/uploads/#{memory.file_name}", :controls => true ) %></td>
>         <td><%= memory.file_path %></td>
>         <td><%= link_to 'Show', memory %></td>
>         <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_memory_path(memory) %></td>
>         <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', memory, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
>       </tr>
>     <% end %>   </tbody> </table>
> 
> <br>
> 
> <%= link_to 'New Memory', new_memory_path %>
```

This will give you the output. but your database should contain file_name and file_path.

Further assistance you can ask me.